# Is there a good list that helps sort out the relative market of grocery store chains in the US?

Tags: usa, online-resources, food-and-drink

So, when I travel, I'm kinda strange.  I prefer to pick up local produce and/or eat at grocery store salad / sushi bars. (Restaurants are tasty, but much more expensive!)

On the East Coast, I'm pretty familiar with most chains - at the higher end, there is Wegman's and Harris Teeter, somewhere in the middle is Giant and Safeway, and at the low wend would be Bloom and/or Fud Lion. (And no, that is not a mispelling.  Food Lion doesn't deserve two vowels) I can pretty well sort out how decent the quality of the food is going to be by knowing things like:

- whether or not there would be a fresh bakery
- whether or not they sell 1% milk (It's amazing how hard it is to find anything other than whole or skim in cities!)
- whether or not they sell sushi :) or have certain "bars."

The problem, of course, is when I travel.  When I was commuting to Florida, I began to understand Publix, and in Austin, I eventually found a grocery store I liked - but I'm wondering if someone has already done these kinds of comparisons for me?  At very least, a list of what the chains in given US cities are would be nice - but for extra credit said site should begin to sort these stores into the value end and the quality end of the spectrum.

Obviously, given the name of a chain, I can look up their websites, but is there a comparison type list that isn't so biased? (I'm sure Food Lion thinks they're low price and high quality!)

Does such a non-vendor produced website list exist, so that when I go to a new area, I can already have a sense of the correct grocery chains to try out?

Comment: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/04/02/best-supermarkets_n_1398053.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_supermarket_chains_in_the_United_States.  Though I don't think this question can be definitevely answered because a lot of the better supermarkets may not be available in some of the places you might visit.

Comment: In some of the places I visited or lived: Mass: Roche Brothers, IN: Marsh, Kroger, NY, NJ: Fairway Markets, Shop Rite (not all locations), Wegman's, PA: Giant, ShopRite, Wegman's Nationwide: Costco, Whole Foods.  A&P and it's subsidiaries generally suck.

Comment: Bloom is operated by Food Lion.  From 'upmarket' to 'downmarket', Food Lion's brands are Bloom, Food Lion, and Bottom Dollar (at least in the DC area).  Obviously, your experience may vary, but Bloom is targeted for upmarket.  However, it looks like they're undoing the branding and just making everything food lion: http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/capital-business/post/food-lions-owner-closing-126-stores-retiring-bloom-banner/2012/01/12/gIQAEWnutP_blog.html